# Get elements from <ng-content></ng-content> of the same component in ts file

Tags: angular

I am trying to get elements from ng-content which is present in the same component, but I am unable to get them.

Component html

```
<div>
<ng-content #action></ng-content>
<app-comp2></app-comp2>
</div>
```

Component's .ts

```
@ContentChildren('action') content:QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

I am always getting undefined. What could be the reason?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Please show your parent and child components clearly. Are you maybe looking for `@ViewChildren`?

Comment: It's the same component. ng-content will have some content, so I want to get those elements in my ts file.

Comment: Then can you show the parent component? How is this component used?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to get this.content inside onInit, ng-content will not be available till the ngAfterContentInit hook is called. Try using this.content inside ngAfterContentInit or ngAfterViewInit

```js
ngAfterContentInit(){
  console.log(this.content)
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I have tried both before as well.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChildren) mentions the selector inside `@ContentChildren` selects a template reference in the content. Example:
Parent.html

```html
<app-content-component>
  <div id="div1" #action>This is the content of component</div>
  <div id="div2">This is other content of component</div>
</app-content-component>
```

Component.ts

```js
// this now contains div1 but not div2
@ContentChildren('action') content: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

It is **not** possible to get all the Elements in the content with `@ContentChildren`. You can only use the selector for the following cases:

> The following selectors are supported.
>
> - Any class with the @Component or @Directive decorator
> - A template reference variable as a string (e.g. query <my-component #cmp> with @ContentChildren('cmp'))
> - Any provider defined in the child component tree of the current component (e.g. @ContentChildren(SomeService) someService: SomeService)
> - Any provider defined through a string token (e.g. @ContentChildren('someToken') someTokenVal: any)
> - A TemplateRef (e.g. query  with @ContentChildren(TemplateRef) template;)

As you actually project the content with `ng-content` you can actually use `@ViewChild` to get the content, but not on the `ng-content` element directly as it will be replaced by the content. You can however just wrap the `ng-content` in a `ng-container` and add a template variable to it. Example:

Component.html

```html
<div>
  <ng-container #myContent>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  <ng-container>
  <app-comp2></app-comp2>
</div>
```

Component.ts

```js
// this now contains a reference to the ng-container
@ViewChild('myContent') content: ElementRef;
```